# Using Meta or Chat

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've noticed that Sports meta is often used as a quasi chat room. Questions are asked, but without any answers. Some of them contain huge comment lists.

I'm in favour of getting clear answers to the questions people ask, otherwise you must start a chat in the chat room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is ultimately that we don't have a very active meta.

Ideally, chat is the place that a quick answer to an established meta question can be answered. IE: is X in scope? can be answered quickly in chat if it's a definite yes, but if there is a question then that kind of thing needs to go to meta so the *entire* community can see it.

Chat is a very niche locale on SE sites, it's not well known and it's not used by most people. However, the *formalized* location for making site decisions is meta.

However, on a site like this one, meta participation is kinda low and meta voting is even worse than meta participation. That simply means that often meta posts are conversations between a few key users.

Sure it makes it look an awful lot like chat, but ultimately things are decided here and not in chat.

As far as questions that have a series of comments instead of an answer, sometimes that's juts the best way to figure out the situation.

Looking at the questions that are in the unanswered tab (either having no answer or no upvoted answer), most of them are announcements that require no response unless someone disputes the announcement.

Comment: I would like to investigate close reasons including "status is completed" or "evaluation has ended" for example as some meta discussions fall in this category. This would justify questions that fall into the "unanswered" category.

Comment: @edmastermind29 I think that [tag:Status-completed] *should* remove it from unasnwered questions on meta. But not it doesn't seem to...hmmm

Comment: Hence, the dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree Jacob Jan.

It will give a better overview to what the community feels/thinks/wants, rather than a set of comments or overly complete answers.

Some stats: of the 130 questions asked, 55 have an accepted answer, 11 have no answer at all.

Feel free to add your own answer, so that we can vote on your opinion !!

Comment: Glad to know that Jacob Jan and Jacob Jan are in agreement :)

Comment: @edmastermind29 me, myself and I.......